# Do colonial nations provide their motherland with manpower or increased force limits?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm rather new to EU4 (with CoP) and am having fun creating a cluster of colonial nations in North America as Great Britain. I'm considering going on a bigger conquest spree in Europe, and to do this I'll definitely need more manpower.

I can't for the life of me find anything on whether CN's contribute manpower (or raise force limits?) for their owners. The wiki page on [Vassals](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Vassal) suggests that *they* have the force limit raised (but not the man power?), and the page for [subject nations](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Subject_nation) tells me that Trade Companies do not contribute manpower - which suggests that normal Vassals (and CNs?) do.

Thanks!

Comment: Still unclear to me, so I've done a couple of experiments on an older save. Freeing all my colonies did not change my total manpower when it was at a maximum - and (unlike manpower) the force limit indicator gives info on how many provinces contribute, and this doesn't include any CN provinces. So it looks to me like they do not. So presumably this makes colonising the new world/Australia a significantly smaller source of manpower than taking provinces in, say, India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not receive manpower from any subject nation.

Colonial nations increase naval force limit, but not army force limit.

Answer (score 3):

- Vassals/Client states = land force limit
- Marches = nothing
- PU = nothing
- Trade company = 1 naval limit per 2 provinces, zero manpower contribution
- colonial nations = naval force limit
- protectorates = nothing

Subjects don't directly give bonus manpower, however they (trade companies aside) can help you in battles allowing you to save your manpower (though protectorates are limited in what kinds of wars they can fight), since they have their own pools of AT LEAST 10k manpower to build troops from even if they only have 1 province.

So there's no actual direct bonus, but you do "get" extra manpower by having subjects, hence why France having his vassals pre-integrated in recent patches was seen as a huge nerf since now it has to fight it's wars with only it's own manpower pool, and why most people prefer to keep the HRE on the 2nd to last reform, since you keep all the reform bonuses and have the entire HRE as a massive vassal swarm that doesn't take up relation slots and 4-5x the amount of manpower pool worth of armies then you'd have from uniting it and can only compare their individual strength vs yours, instead of all vassals relative to you.

Trade Companies unlike all the other examples aren't separate countries and are instead provinces you retain control of but add to a trade company charter to gain a huge boost in local trade power and the ability to ignore unrest from religious or cultural differences, but at the cost of all manpower you would've gained and half the taxes and a flat .5 naval force limit per province. On the other hand, it's most likely you'd have had a minimum 75% autonomy and wouldn't have gotten much anyway, where as the province isn't locally penalized from the overseas autonomy when it's in a trade company since the province is considered under local management